normal map baking issue(broken map, linear color space)
I was making a character model with blender, then I baked them with Marmoset. I followed tutorials but I guess I missed something. When I connect baked normal map to my model, it seems splitted.. Do you guys know what the problem is? I checked uv but there's nothing overlapped.
Also, when I connect normal map with image texture nodes, there are 6 different linear color spaces. I connected them all, but still don't know which one is right.
Please help.

Thank you

If you upload your file to blend-exchange.com, it will be much easier for people to help you,

I just checked this comment and uploaded my file. Thank you.

Psd is not included

I just uploaded, I'm sorry for late reply
